# Relacionamento ManyToOne / OneToMany TypeOrm não salva chave estrangeira

Tags: node.js, sqlite3, typeorm

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma API em node usando o TypeOrm e SQLite3, porem ao utilizar o relacionamento ManyToOne / OneToMany, ele não salva a chave estrangeira. O cenário é o seguinte: Eu tenho um usuário que pode ter uma ou mais listas e uma lista só pode pertencer a um usuário. Ao implementar isso com typeorm, ele não salva a chave estrangeira.

metodo save da lista:

```
    async save(request: Request, response: Response) {
    let { user_id, products } = request.body;

    products = products.map(product => {
      return { id: product };
    });

    const listRepository = getRepository(List);

    const data = { user_id, products };

    const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      user_id: Yup.number().required(),
      products: Yup.array(
        Yup.object().shape({
          id: Yup.number().required(),
        }),
      ),
    });

    await schema.validate(data, {
      abortEarly: false,
    });

    const list = listRepository.create(data);

    await listRepository.save(list);

    return response.status(201).json(list);
  },
```

Modelo da lista:

```
@Entity()
export default class List {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToMany(type => Product)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'list_product',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'list_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'product_id',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
  })
  products: Product[];

  @ManyToOne(() => User, user => user.lists)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: User;
}
```

O modelo da lista possui dois relacionamentos, um ManyToMany e o ManyToOne(que não está salvando o id do usuário na tabela)

Modelo do usuario:

```
@Entity('user')
export default class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @OneToMany(() => List, list => list.user)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  lists: List[];
}
```

Quando eu mando uma requisição pra url que chama o método save, ele salva os dados na tabela de muitos pra muitos, porem não salva o id do usuário na tabela "list". Ou seja, A relação N:M está funcionando perfeitamente, porem o relacionamento 1:N não está funcionando, ele simplesmente salva o id do usuário como null.

Comment: Acho que o problema aí é esse **@JoinCollumn()** nas duas entidades!

Comment: @LeAndrade acho que esse não é o problema em si. Eu fiz os testes e mesmo antes com o `@JoinCollumn` em um so modelo, ele já não estava salvando o usuario na lista. Segui os mesmo passos que um video, porem não obtive sucesso, mas obrigado pela resposta!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver depois de um pouco de estudo da minha aplicação. O problema não estava no código em si, mas sim na forma como eu mandava a referencia do usuário. Quando fazia a requisição ao servidor, eu enviava algo assim:

```
{
    "user": 1,
    "products": [1,2
    ]
}
```

E no metodo save, eu uso o Yup pra validar os dados, e a minha validação estava assim:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      user_id: Yup.number().required(),
      products: Yup.array(
        Yup.object().shape({
          id: Yup.number().required(),
        }),
      ),
    });
```

Logo, a minha requisição passava pela validação pois eu realmente estava mandando um numero inteiro, que no caso é o id do usuário. Porem, percebi que na hora de salvar, ele não associava o id do usuario a um usuario do banco de dados:

```
const list = listRepository.create(data);

console.log(list); // aqui ele me mostrava que apenas os produtos eram associados

await listRepository.save(list);

return response.status(201).json(list);
```

Ao que tudo indica, o TypeORM espera um objeto quando se trata de chave estrangeira (não achei nada relacionado a isso, então se alguem tiver algum link que possa ler, ficaria muito grato). Logo, linha solução foi passar um objeto com o id do usuario dentro ao inves de só o id do usuario:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "products": [1,2
    ]
}
```

Depois, atualizei a validação do Yup também:

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
      user: Yup.object().shape({
        id: Yup.number().required(),
      }),
      products: Yup.array(
        Yup.object().shape({
          id: Yup.number().required(),
        }),
      ),
    });
```

E pronto! Agora ele salva uma nova lista já com o Id do usuário e também salva os produtos da lista na tabela de muitos para muitos também :)